# Bieberbach theorem

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, integer-lattices

Bieberbach theorem say that every discrete cocompact subgroup in $Isom(\mathbb{R}^n )$ contains a translational subgroup of finite index.
(the translations forming an abelian normal subgroup of finite index)

1) Why this subgroup is a lattice in $ \mathbb{R}^n$ ?

2) Can you give me a simple proof in dimension 2 ?.

Comment: There's a pretty naive argument: $Isom(R^n)$ projects onto $O_n$ by forgetting the translation component, i.e. it is a semi-direct product.  Consider what happens if the projection was not finite.

Answer (score 2):

Let's denote the crystallographic (i.e. discrete and cocompact) by $\Gamma$, and write $\operatorname{Isom}(\mathbb{R}^n) = O(n) \ltimes \mathbb{R}^n$. The first Bieberbach theorem, as stated in [1], is:

> If $\Gamma \subset \operatorname{Isom}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a crystallographic group then the set of translations $\Gamma \cap (\{I_n\} \times \mathbb{R}^n)$ is a torsion free and finitely generated abelian group of rank $n$, and is a maximal abelian and normal subgroup of finite index.

The [fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group#Classification) then implies that $T \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$, which of course means $T$ is a lattice.

For the proof, I'll refer to [1], the second chapter is dedicated entirely to proving the Bieberbach theorems. I do however doubt that the proof given there will simplify a lot in dimension $2$.

Perhaps of some interest to you is the following theorem (thm 2.2 in [1]) by Zassenhaus:

> A group $\Gamma$ is isomorphic to a crystallographic group of dimension $n$ if and only if $\Gamma$ has a normal, free abelian subgroup $\mathbb{Z}^n$ of finite index which is a maximal abelian subgroup of $\Gamma$.

[1] [Szczepanski, Andrzej. *Geometry of crystallographic groups*. Vol. 4. World Scientific, 2012.](https://books.google.com/books?id=wX26CgAAQBAJ)

Answer (score 1):

You can probably find the answers in Chapters 24, 25 and 26 of Armstrong's [*Groups and symmetry*](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387966755), which gives a pretty elementary treatment of the subject (Chapter 26, in particular, concentrates on dimension $2$).

Comment: Thank you so much, that the best group theory book I have seen!

Comment: This reference does not contain a proof. It assumes that a wallpaper group has a lattice as its translation subgroup as part of the definition.